# MOSFET choice - PWM LED strip

Tags: mosfet, pwm, esp8266, led-strip, component-selection

I'm looking to PWM an LED strip with an ESP8266 (3.3 V PWM signal) with the following characteristics:

- Red channel: 12 V, 300 mA
- Green channel: 12 V, 250 mA
- Blue channel: 12 V, 250 mA

[As I understand it](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/619284/8219), a MOSFET is best suited for this task, so I've been reading as much as I can to understand which specific parts might be suitable. Ideally I would like a through-hole component, but these seem harder to find, so I've got some surface-mount ones in the list too. This is what I've come up with:

- [BSS816NW](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BSS816NW-DS-v02_03-en.pdf?fileId=db3a304335113a6301351e704a2e1332)

  - ❓ Only slight concern is that graph 5 doesn't show a \$V_{gs}\$ greater than 2.5 V. Am I missing something here that would make this unsuitable?
  - It's SMT, which isn't my first choice.
  - Low \$R_{DS(on)}\$ resistance, which is good.
- [TN0702](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/TN0702%20C080813.pdf)

  - It has a higher \$R_{DS(on)}\$ resistance.
  - It's THT!
  - It's expensive!
- [FDN337N](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fdn337n-d.pdf)

  - It's SMT.
  - Low \$R_{DS(on)}\$ resistance.

I'm leaning towards the [TN0702](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/TN0702%20C080813.pdf) as it meets my THT criteria, but could use one of the others if necessary. So my question is: Are any/all of these components suitable for the job? I've not used MOSFETs before and am quite inexperienced with electronics, so would be grateful of any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they will work. The through-hole one will dissipate 1/4 to 1/3 W. The two SMTs are much better electronically.

Comment: Thanks @RussellH. Out of interest, where did you see the 1/4 - 1/4 W dissipation? I can only see the 1 W mentioned at the top of the second page.

Comment: Used a calculation based on the current you intend to use and the  on resistance. The on resistance for the SMTs is a factor of ten lower.

Comment: Gottcha, thanks!